# Can we use C style static variables inside Objective C instance methods?

Tags: objective-c

Whenever I have to use a BOOL flag which maintains its value across multiple calls for taking  some action in an instance method  of a class or a counter for that method call.

I always use an instance variable to store those values even though I am only using them inside that method only.

In C I would use a static variable with that function's scope to deal with such situation,
Since most of the Objetive C is some form of C only,

is it possible that I do same with normal selectors and when they finally get turned into IMPs, they work as the same C style static variables.

Will this work or there are issues that I am missing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can declare static variables in Objective-C methods, since Objective-C is a superset of C.